# js generated form

Tags: jquery

I have a js generated form (i.e. I echo a form from js code).

So I wrote a submit handler that is activated when that form is submitted using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form-coures').submit(function(event){
```

At least this is what I want to achieve.

The issue here is that when I submit that form the handler isn't called?!

Any ideas?

Note: if I define that same form not through js everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without actually seeing all of your code, but you register the submit event handler on document ready, at which time the DOM element `form-courses` wouldn't exist yet (if you are generating it after page load using javascript).  Register the event *after* you add the form to the page.

Comment: How can I register the event?

Comment: With the same `$('#form-coures').submit(function(event){...` but after your script adds the form.  Or, use delegation as @ethagnawl answer shows.

Answer (score 0):

The form doesn't exist when you're attaching the event handler.

Use event delegation `$(document).on('submit', 'form', function () {...})`

Answer (score -1):

well... i've never done this with JQuery (e.g.: make an entire form programmatically), but as far as ideas, have you thought about hokking an onclick event to your submit button instead?

Comment: Don't do that. Then when someone presses enter on one of the fields, the form will submit in the usual way; your jQuery code will not catch it.